# Are commitment requirements different for the Poker Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, stackexchange, meta

Don't get me wrong, I'm pleased to have been marked as "Satisfying my Commitment" to this SE site, but doing so has confused me. Most of the Area51 discussion indicates that Commitment Satisfaction requires a total of 10 combined answers and questions. Nothing else is supposed to effect this.

However, my current status and notification seem to counter this.
Currently I'm at 5q, 3a, 257Rep, Badge: 1s + 7c, Some wiki tags and votes.

So, I'm confused if the commitment requirement is as often discussed.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are the same as for all the SE 2.0 sites.  The exact requirements are not made public because we don't want people to game it.

Taking a look at your account, you have indeed met the requirements though. (: